# Python: var set in __init__ not available

Tags: python, django

I'm failing to understand the following behaviour inside my debugger:

```
(Pdb++) ll
58         def __init__(self, content=None):
59             import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
60             self.__content = BytesIO()
61             self.__len = 0
62  ->         self.read_started = False
63             if content is not None:
64                 self.write(content)
(Pdb++) !self.__len
 *** AttributeError: 'FakePayload' object has no attribute '__len'
```

instead I can prove that the object has an attribute like that:

```
(Pdb++) fpl = environ['wsgi.input']
(Pdb++) fpl._    -> <TAB-TAB>
_FakePayload__len
```

I have never seen anything like that before and I'd be glad for any hint to make me understand.

Comment: Don't use double-underscore prefixes. It almost never does what you want.

Comment: I understand. but that is native django test client code... so where is the mistake? https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.5/django/test/client.py#L60

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake?

Comment: I'm hunting an exception here. and it fails here https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.5/django/test/client.py#L74 with `__len` not existing. But `_FakePayload__len` is existing.

Comment: Read the linked answer. From outside the class, you can't access attributes with double-underscore prefixes without using the name-mangled version. But code inside the class itself can use the original name. Maybe you should ask a separate question about the problem you are actually experiencing.

Comment: kabooom. stupid me. I failed to interpret the docu properly. you're telling me that by using `self.__len` from within the class def and by using pdb - python is considering this an outside access?! but yes, can be and helps me to keep debuggin... THX!